# Multiple partial string matches in dataframe count

Tags: r, string, count, pattern-matching

I have been looking around for a solution on other topics but I haven't found it. I am looking to count several partial string matches. The strings are in a dataframe but I have tried as well in a (character) vector.

Example input:

```
authors <- c("Edward","Kelly","Simon")
df <- 
Text                                 Date      
Edward was the king of ...           2011          
Kelly has ..                         2014           
Last year Simon..                    2009           
Did you know Edward..                1999
```

What I want as output is:

```
Author                               Count 
Edward                                2
Kelly                                 1           
Simon                                 1
```

Important as well is that each row in the column text is only matched once. So if the name is mentioned twice in the input cell, it should still only match once.

I have tried something like:

```
sum(str_count(df$Text,c("Edward")))
```

Which works for one input name, but not for several. I hope someone can help me out with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the 'authors', get the `str_count`, `sum`, and `enframe` it to get a single dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(authors, ~ str_count(df$Text, .x) %>% 
                       sum %>%
                       set_names(.x) %>% 
                       enframe(name = "Author", value = "count")) %>%
    arrange(desc(count))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Author    count
#   <chr>  <int>
#1 Edward     2
#2 Kelly      1
#3 Simon      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I needed! Is there some way to pass a desc = T argument to the tibble?

Comment: @Bastje  Updated the post